# Inconsistent results in R using .Call inside lapply

Tags: r, rcpp

I've created a package using the Rcpp package's `Rcpp.package.skeleton` function containing one .cpp file with a C++ function returning 0:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
RcppExport SEXP just_zero() {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RNGScope __rngScope;
    return wrap(0.0);
END_RCPP
}
```

When I install and load the package from R I can call the function with .Call via lapply. As expected, it (appears to) always return 0:

```
> x <- lapply(seq(10000), function(i) { x <- .Call('just_zero'); stopifnot(x == 0); x } )
#*no errors!*
```

However, apparently the value which is returned by `lapply` contains non-zeros:

```
> range(simplify2array(x))
[1] 0 3
```

Unfortunately, using `set.seed` doesn't make these returned values reproducible, and sometimes I do get `[1] 0 0`, sometimes other values, e.g. `[1] "0" "TRUE"`. An additional clue is that removing the line `Rcpp::RNGScope __rngScope;` fixes the problem.

Why are there non-zero elements in the object returned by `lapply` (particularly as we've checked the values returned by `.Call`), and how come using `RNGScope` is causing it?

I've reproduced this behaviour on Linux and OS X. Session info from OS X pasted below:

```
> sessionInfo()
R Under development (unstable) (2016-08-03 r71023)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X Mavericks 10.9.5

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] bug_1.0         devtools_1.12.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.4.0   withr_1.0.2   memoise_1.0.0 Rcpp_0.12.6   git2r_0.15.0
[6] digest_0.6.10
```

Comment: The `Rcpp::wrap()` helper is **not** templated.  It takes its argument, and returns a `SEXP`.  But as @coatless explained to you, all this can be had more easily via Rcpp Attributes.

Comment: Thanks! Have now reflected in the question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example that reproduces the issue consistently for me.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void dummy() {}

extern "C" SEXP just_zero() {
  Rcpp::RNGScope rngScope;
  return wrap(0.0);
}

/*** R
n <- 1E5
x <- unlist(lapply(seq(n), function(i) {
  .Call('just_zero')
}))

unique(x)
*/
```

Calling `Rcpp::sourceCpp()` on this gives me e.g.

```
> unique(x)
 [1]     0  8371 16021 20573 25109 43103 47563 56438 60852 78413 82773 95765
```

What's causing this issue? To understand this, we need to understand the definition of `RNGScope`: we can see it here:

https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/9fbdf78fe225607dc2c8af7267a6840af0aba10e/inst/include/Rcpp/stats/random/random.h#L27-L31

and the methods it uses are defined here:

https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/9fbdf78fe225607dc2c8af7267a6840af0aba10e/src/api.cpp#L63-L75

with the most important function, `PutRNGState`, being defined here:

https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/1c88a057594a0348f2bf75514a8015caeedbff93/src/main/RNG.c#L424-L446

Now, this is effectively what happens when `just_zero` is called:

1. `RNGScope` object is created, with its associated destructor primed to run.
2. The result of `wrap(0.0)`, being a `REALSXP` with length 1 and value 0, is created. Note that this object is **unprotected** and so is eligible for garbage collection.
3. The function returns, and the `RNGScope` destructor is called.
4. This calls the R routine `PutRNGstate()`, which itself will call `allocVector`, thereby triggering the garbage collector. This implies the `SEXP` object you wanted to return can be collected, and hence will be garbage!

So, in sum -- use Rcpp attributes, as it will take care of doing this all safely for you.

---

To understand why Rcpp attributes makes this 'safe', look at the generated code:

```
// just_zero
SEXP just_zero();
RcppExport SEXP sourceCpp_0_just_zero() {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject __result;
    Rcpp::RNGScope __rngScope;
    __result = Rcpp::wrap(just_zero());
    return __result;
END_RCPP
}
```

Note that the output result is assigned to `Rcpp::RObject`, which protects the object, and we ensure that this object is constructed *before* the `RNGScope` object, which ensures it will remain protected while the `RNGScope` destructor is run.

Comment: great explanation! @Daniel , this is the answer you seek.

Comment: Thanks for the great clear answer, and for making the issue reproducible! I suppose garbage collection is very unlikely after a single call to `just_zero` and hence the line `stopifnot(x == 0)` in the original question doesn't trigger any errors.

Comment: Doesn't the original question with `stopifnot()` imply that garbage collection / corruption occurs _after_ returning to R? If it were garbage collected in C++ then it would come back corrupted.

Comment: Interesting, I think you're right. Although I believe my analysis is still correct, perhaps there is something deeper going on.

Answer (score 3):

This is not fully an answer, but I'll expand it as it goes. However, I'm not able to reproduce this behavior on macOS.

I believe the issue you are encountering is due to your use of the RcppExport alongside Rcpp Attributes, e.g. :

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
RcppExport SEXP just_zero()
```

Should be done via:

```
library("Rcpp")
cppFunction("double just_zero() {
    return 0.0;
}")

x <- lapply(seq(10000), function(i) { x <- just_zero(); stopifnot(x == 0); x } )

all(range(simplify2array(x)) == 0)
```

or place the following into `file.cpp`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double just_zero() {
    return 0.0;
}

/*** R
x <- lapply(seq(10000), function(i) { x <- just_zero(); stopifnot(x == 0); x } )
all(range(simplify2array(x)) == 0)
*/
```

If the intent is to use `sourceCpp()`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer - using sourceCpp on the cpp code in the question fixes the issue (passing verbose=TRUE shows that it expands the code a little to assign the value of wrap to a variable before returning - indeed installing the package with the code printed out by sourceCpp fixes the issue too). Removing the RcppAttributes hasn't helped unfortunately - presumably they're not used when installing the package...